# how to create index on this sql statement?

Tags: mysql, indexing

```
EXPLAIN 
select * 
  from goods 
 where start_time <= 1491894088 
   and end_time > 1491894088 
   and type = 2
```

id:1

select_type：simple

table:good_price

type:all

possible_key:ed

key:null

rows:2345(all)

I have try make index (start_time,end_time,special_type) ,but it doesn't work,
any ideas? thanks

Comment: Show your code and any error message. Also show the table schema.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done.  A partial solution is to have

```
INDEX(special_type, start_time)
INDEX(special_type, end_time)
```

The Optimizer will, after picking one of those queries,

1. Look into the index for `special_type = 2` at 1491894088
2. Scan forward (or backward) to find all the rows on one side of it
3. Reach into the data to check the other end.

This *might* work slightly better (due to ICP), but I am not sure:

```
INDEX(special_type, start_time, end_time)
INDEX(special_type, end_time, start_time)
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...` for any formulations you try.  That will help us see if the indexes help.

How frequent is `special_type=2`?

Note: I put `special_type` *first* in the index because, the Optimizer stops using index can't be used after it hits a range (`start_time` in the one you attempted).

[*More on building an index.*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/)